# How can I use and IF statement within a REPLACE () statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, replace, reporting

got a query in regards to using an IF statement within a REPLACE statement (if it is possible!)

Example:

```
REPLACE("Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status",'Widowed','Widower')
```

So that works, but I need an IF statement in there to distinguish between whether they are a Widower or a Widow based on their gender (which can be pulled from another column).

Would I place an IF statement before starting the REPLACE statement?

Example:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(IF("Worker"."Gender" = 'M')"Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status",'Widowed','Widower')IF("Worker"."Gender" = 'F')"Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status",'Widowed','Widow')
```

Not sure if I'm nesting this wrong but I can't seem to get this to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm) to decide which replacement value to use:

```
REPLACE("Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status",
    'Widowed', CASE "Worker"."Gender" WHEN 'F' THEN 'Widow' ELSE 'Widower' END)
```

Demo:

```
with "Worker" (id, "Gender") as (
  select 1, 'M' from dual
  union all select 2, 'F' from dual
),
"Person Legislative Information" (id, "Marital Status") as (
  select 1, 'Widowed' from dual
  union all select 2, 'Widowed' from dual
)
SELECT "Worker"."Gender", "Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status",
  REPLACE("Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status",
    'Widowed', CASE "Worker"."Gender" WHEN 'F' THEN 'Widow' ELSE 'Widower' END)
    AS "New Marital Status"
FROM "Worker"
JOIN "Person Legislative Information"
ON "Person Legislative Information".id = "Worker".id;

G Marital New Marital Status                               
- ------- -------------------------------------------------
M Widowed Widower                                          
F Widowed Widow
```

Comment: I upvoted because I liked this answer.  I initially thought of a CASE outside of the REPLACE, but I like this version of using it inside.  Also, the example and validation data is well done.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a CASE statement

```
SELECT
  CASE "Worker"."Gender"
    WHEN 'F' THEN
      REPLACE("Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status", 'Widowed', 'Widow')
    ELSE
      REPLACE("Person Legislative Information"."Marital Status", 'Widowed', 'Widower')
  END marital_status
```

Comment: I'm sure sure if this is the syntax for Oracle - but give it a go

Comment: It was close, but I've tweaked it so it actually works in Oracle... *8-)

Comment: Thanks Trent, this was helpful!